# kotlin-multiplatform : how to use Kotlin Flow in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have created a kotlin multi-platform library to design Domain layer that targets JVM and JS (nodejs and browser). Domain depends on UseCase, UseCase depends on Repository, Repository depends on Service and Database. AFAIK, Kotlin Coroutines work across platforms (JS/JVM/Native).

I have a function that returns `Flow`, instead of `Promise`.

```
fun getUserList() : Flow<List<User>>{...}
```

Reason is, I want to update UI as soon as there is any change in Database. On JVM (or Android), I know how to consume Flow. But don't understand how to consume it from plain Javascript(or TypeScript) (not Kotlin-JS). Even I didn't find any supporting article that explains about using Flow for JS.

Can anyone help me out with this? Any help will be appreciated!

PS: My Javascript Skills are intermediate :P

Comment: I think `Flow` and suspend functions in general are not really meant to be used by platform code. So I guess your solution with using a callback may be the only one :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, till I find some official solution to this problem, here is what I have come up with:

Instead of returning Flow, I created a wrapper function take two arguments:

```
@JsName("getUsersListWithUpdatesJs")
fun UserUseCase.getUsersListWithUpdatesJs(
    success: (List<User>) -> Unit,
    error: (Throwable) -> Unit
) = GlobalScope.promise {
    try {
        getUsersList().collect {
            success(it)
        }
    } catch (exception: Throwable) {
        error(exception)
    }
}
```

Then I published the Js library on our Nexus Server.

Added as dependency into JS project using npm.

Then, the usage:

```
import * as domain from "my-multiplatform-library";
…
…
…
domain.com.abc.usecase.createUserUseCaseJs().then(
      (useCase) => {
        console.log(useCase);
        useCase. getUsersListWithUpdatesJs(
            (list) => {
                // This block should be called twice. For Empty and Non-empty array
                console.log("Response", list)
            },
            (error) => {
                // Ignore this block for now
            },
        );
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
```

Comment: If the flow contains multiple values, then this is broken since a promise can only be resolved once. If the flow only ever contains a single value, why use Flow instead of Deferred?

Comment: @araqnid I got your point. But we will get more than one value as update which is the reason I considered using Flow.

Comment: @araqnid the promise is for tracking the completion of the whole function (and flow collection). The individual values of the flow are passed through the callback, not through the promise, so the problem you mention doesn't apply here.

Comment: Ah, I misread the interface. It's still a bit weird, since the error is passed to a callback and then the promise resolves successfully.. it feels like the Flow should be adapted to an Observable